# Vector-valued function interpolation using NumPy/SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Is there a way to interpolate a vector-valued function using [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy)/[SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy)?

There are plenty of offerings that work on scalar-valued functions, and I guess I can use one of those to estimate each component of the vector separately, but is there a way to do it more efficiently?

To elaborate, I have a function `f(x) = V`, where `x` is scalar and `V` is a vector. I also have a collection of `xs` and their corresponding `Vs`. I would like to use it to interpolate and estimate `V` for an arbitrary `x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The interpolation function `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` also works on vector-valued data for the interpolant (not for vector-valued argument data though). Thus, as long as `x` is scalar, you can use it directly.

The following code is a slight extension of the example given in [the scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#id3):

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
>>> y = np.array([np.exp(-x/3.0), 2*x])
>>> f = interp1d(x, y)
>>> f(2)
array([ 0.51950421,  4.        ])
>>> np.array([np.exp(-2/3.0), 2*2])
array([ 0.51341712,  4.        ])
```

Note that 2 is not in the argument vector `x`, thus the interpolation error for the first component in `y` in this example.