# Interpolation in vector-valued multi-variate function

Tags: python, interpolation

In Python, I'm trying to construct a routine that interpolates in vector-valued data in a multi-dimensional (5+) parameter space. i.e. I have a function that takes a number of input variables and returns a number of output variables. At the moment, there is one call for each element of the vector. The data is in a columned file, so I retrieve it with

```
import numpy
[x_data,y_data,f1_data,f2_data] = numpy.loadtxt('data',unpack=True)
```

Then, I instantiate individual interpolators using SciPy's functions, like

```
from scipy import interpolate
f1 = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator((x_data,y_data),f1_data)
f2 = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator((x_data,y_data),f2_data)
...
```

Now, when I make the interpolation call, I have to interpolate for each value `f1`, `f2`, etc. even though really it should be achievable as one operation. And I'm guessing that making one interpolation should be faster than making 5 or more.

*Is there a way to construct a vector- (or array-) valued interpolator?*

I tried constructing the interpolator with

```
f = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator((x_data,y_data),(f1_data,f2_data,...))
```

but it returns the error

> ValueError: different number of values and points

I've also read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129958/vector-valued-function-interpolation-using-numpy-scipy) but it's about a vector-valued function of a scalar, which can apparently be handled by `interp1d`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html) expects to receive its data in row-major order: for example in your case, the first argument needs to be an array of pairs, not a pair of arrays. Since you transposed your data when you loaded it, you'll have to transpose it back again before passing it to `LinearNDInterpolator`. Try something like:

```
points = numpy.array((x, y)).T
values = numpy.array((f1, f2)).T
f = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! On reading your answer, I realised that I should've worked it out myself...