# Python interpolare a function or array in a 2D (or nD) grid of parameters

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a 2D regular grid of parameters that at each point have a model for a 1D model and I would like to interpolate that 1D model array to any point of parameters space (not just the grid nodes).

For 1D grid of 1 parameter (say `A`) with grid values `a` I can do the trick using [interpolate.RectBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline), which generates a function that I can call at any given value of `A`. 
ex:

```
from scipy import interpolate
ip = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(a, x, model, s = 0)
new_model = ip([aa], [x])
```

where `a` is the 1D "grid" or array of values for the parameter A, `x` is the 1D array of discrete pixels at which the model is expressed `f(x) = model(x)`, and `aa` is the new value of A at which I want to interpolate.

For the 2D case one solution would be to compute at each pixel of x (each x_i) the interpolation of the 2 parameters using **RectBivariateSpline** or another method, (like slicing a 3D volume in 2D planes) but that seems cumbersome and does not account for correlation between pixels on the model.

The solution here [Multivariate spline interpolation in python/scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238250/multivariate-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy) does not quite apply to my case as I need a complete array to be returned and I need to evaluate at different points on different moments.

From the solutions on [scipy interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html): Both [LinearNDinterp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator)
and [NearestNDInterp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator) might work, but I don't know how to do a similar thing as with **RectBivariateSpline**, i.e. feed it the 2D (or nD) parameters grid, the pixels array for the model and the model values, and then get back a interpolated model for the same pixels but different parameter values `grid(a1, a2, ... an; x) -> model(A1', A2', ... An'; x)`

The solution might be here: [Interpolation in vector-valued multi-variate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391747/interpolation-in-vector-valued-multi-variate-function) but I don't know how to reinterpret it to my case...

Ultimately what I would like to do is have the function `f(A1, A2, ... An; x)` (or something equivalent) and with some Montecarlo explore in a finer grid the parameters space when comparing the model with data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since nobody has come with any help I'll post my own solution.
As hinted starting from the solution on  [Interpolation in vector-valued multi-variate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391747/interpolation-in-vector-valued-multi-variate-function) and with little more research on **LinearNDinterpolation** from [Extrapolate with LinearNDInterpolator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516762/extrapolate-with-linearndinterpolator) and basically here [Python 4D linear interpolation on a rectangular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119892/python-4d-linear-interpolation-on-a-rectangular-grid) (I missed this in my first search) I adapted it to my case in a quite straightforward way.

```
points = np.array((a1, a2)).T
values = np.array((models))

ip = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(points, values)
p = [A1_new, A2_new]
new_model = ip([point])[0]
```

Where  a1, a2 are the arrays with the grid points of each of the parameters, for example in a 2x3 grid:

```
a1= [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2]
a2= [3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5]
```

and a plot as example (of my models): [image: 2 models of the grid and the interpolated one from an out of grid point p = (A1', A2')]

With that I can call the "function" ip at any point of the grid that I need, this is also easily extended for higher dimensions `new_model = ip(A1', A2', ...)`.
 Although I have not check the scalability of it with time (if it's linear with N or most probably goes with the power of N.)

I hope this can be of some help to others.